# how to create a timer which triggers an event after 30 seconds in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a module in which there is a requirement to show a timer which shows only seconds. The timer must start from 30 and keep on decrementing down to 0; and after that fire some action and again start from 30. How can I achieve this in javascript?

Answer (score 4):

There you go :)

```
var timer = 30;
function decrementAfter1Second(){
    setTimeout(function(){
       timer--;
       if(timer==0){
          doWhateverYouWantAfter30Seconds();
          timer = 30;
       }
       decrementAfter1Second();
    }, 1000);
}
decrementAfter1Second();
```

Now next time you want to do something in javascript don't be a slacker and read something about the language first ;) because right now i'm assuming you either don't know how to program or you don't know how to use google.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout and clearTimeout. Have the timeout fire every 1 second and then invoke clearTimeout when seconds == 0.

You can find examples of both functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp).

Comment: @vips I've appended a link to examples of the functions in my answer. If you have any specific questions about how they work, I'll gladly answer them.